# Internationalization UIButton

Tags: ios, swift, audio, internationalization, uibutton

I have some button and after you press them I want to play some audio.The name of the button is the name of the audio file

```
private func playAudio(title : String){
    audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource(title, ofType: "wav")!), error: nil)
    isPlayng = true
    audioPlayer.play()
}

@IBAction func soundButton (sender: UIButton){
    if let title = sender.currentTitle{
        switch title {
        case "Stop":
            if isPlayng{
            audioPlayer.stop()
            }
        default:
            playAudio(title)
        }
    }
}
```

So if I localise the stoyboard the title will  be different and it crash because there is no audio file.So there is a way that I can do this without duplicating the audio files.

Answer (score 1):

This is a naive implementation, but maybe it can give you ideas: you could keep the actual file names and the localized file names in a Dictionary (and maybe store them in a Plist file first then load them when the appp launches) and get the actual file name from the localized title:

```
let filesTitles = ["file one": "file1.wav", "fichier un": "file1.wav", "archivo uno": "file1.wav"] // etc

@IBAction func soundButton (sender: UIButton) {
    if let title = sender.currentTitle {
        switch title {
        case "Stop":
            if isPlayng{
                audioPlayer.stop()
            }
        default:
            // if title is `file one` then fileName is `file1.wav`
            let fileName = filesTitles[title]
            playAudio(fileName)
        }
    }
}
```

It's a simple Dictionary in my example, but you can choose any way you like, the idea being *create a table where localized titles correspond to the actual file title.*

Comment: Yes,this will do it,I just want to localise in one langage,and if want to localise more I load the plist with the names from the localied launguage(1 plist for a language)